# Okay to compare pointers returned by RUNTIME_CLASS() macro?

Tags: c++, mfc, rtti

I've got a function that takes a list of `CRuntimeClass` pointers in order to setup a view. I'd like to return without doing anything if the function is called with a list of the same classes that are already setup. Saving the pointer values and comparing them on the next call is currently working, but I want to verify that that's a legal thing to do, and not something that just happens to work. Maybe my doc-search-fu is lacking, but I can't find anywhere that guarantees the pointer value returned from the RUNTIME_CLASS() macro for a given class will be the same for the life of the program. The closest I could find is in the [docs for `CObject::GetRuntimeClass()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a7t4z25b.aspx):

> There is one CRuntimeClass structure for each CObject-derived class.

That implies that the pointer value shouldn't change, but doesn't exactly state it. Does anyone have something a bit more concrete on that? Or is there a better way to compare the CRuntimeClasses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a peek at `afx.h` plus a little of debugging shows that `RUNTIME_CLASS()` returns a pointer to a static member: `static CRuntimeClass class##class_name` (as it can be seen in the definition of `DECLARE_DYNAMIC(class_name)` macro).

As the member is static, the pointer to it does not change during runtime. In other words `static` is your guarantee.

Answer (score 2):

No such guarantee is documented, albeit that it is likely.  You are supposed to use CObject::IsKindOf().